# How to show the grid of a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, grid-layout

I'm creating Tetris for a school project and I'm trying to figure out how to create a grid inside a JPanel. The grid will consist of 10 rows and 22 columns. I have a class Board that contains all the game logic. My role is to implement the class into graphics.

```
public class Board extends JPanel {
...
public Board() {
   ....
    setLayout(new GridLayout(10,22));
    setFocusable(true);
```

I would then add this panel into a JFrame consisted of other panels but the Board panel does not show up. How can I show a visible board nested within the JPanel, even if I don't actually have anything inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You must use border. Example;

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,10));
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));

for (int i =0; i<(10*10); i++){
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
    label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panel.add(label);
}
```